# Two buttons delete each other's set data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two buttons which adds one to the `HomeScore` variable and `GuestScore` variable. I got each button to control their respective database entries, but whenever I press the home score button, it deletes the guest score entry in the database.

It does this in reverse too; whenever I press the guest score button, it deletes the home score value.

[Pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/g8iTC0Ac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt,
You are updating the same reference for both home and guest scores. Take a look at the following two lines:

```
var homeScoreRef = firebase.database().ref("scores/");
var guestScoreRef = firebase.database().ref("scores/");
```

These references are the exact same. If you set one of them, then set the other, the first one will be overwritten.

In your following code, you set those references to their respective values, however, remember that since you made the references point to the exact same piece of the database, you are just overwriting your values with whichever button was pressed.

```
homeScoreRef.set({
    home: HomeScore
});
```

and:

```
guestScoreRef.set({
    guest: GuestScore
});
```

**Try something like this out:**

```
var homeScoreRef = firebase.database().ref("scores/home/");
var guestScoreRef = firebase.database().ref("scores/guest/");
```

or alternatively you could do:

```
var homeScoreRef = firebase.database().ref("scores/").child("home");
var guestScoreRef = firebase.database().ref("scores/").child("guest");
```

**Update:**

After you change the references, then change your `set()` calls to look like this:

```
homeScoreRef.set(
    HomeScore
);

guestScoreRef.set(
    GuestScore
);
```

This should get rid of the extra /home and /guest in your references.

Also, when you say `homeScoreValueRef.on`, where are you getting this? Where is this reference being created? Because I think you meant to do `homeScoreRef.on`,  correct? I think this is why you get the `NaN` error.

If you have more code than what you have shown in your Pastebin, then make sure you update it to reference the proper references, but overall, I believe this is your error.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure how to handle the buttons then because the buttons pointed to home and guest even though their reference was scores. Here is the console error: Uncaught Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains NaN in property 'scores.home.home' It goes to scores/home/home

Comment: In your code your listener says "homeScoreValueRef.on" but where is this homeScoreValueRef being declared?

Comment: Also, I just want to make sure I understand what you are doing. So you have two buttons, and when you click the HomeScore button, you want the database to add "1" to the value in /scores/home and when you click the GuestScore button, you want the database to add "1" to the value in /scores/guests. Is this correct?

Comment: Excellent! It worked, thanks! I put the .child after the references and now it works beautifully!

Comment: Excellent! And not a problem :)